# How to disable internet access through ethernet connected to router

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking, ethernet, synergy

i have two machines

1.Windows 7(Synergy Server) connected to router via ethernet

2.Ubuntu 13.04(Synergy Client) connected to router via Wifi

i  want to disable internet access in windows 7 but i want ethernet network for working of synergy.

is it possible?

Comment: Is it fine if it will be easily fixable from the Win7 machine?

Comment: This is done by creating an interla network.  This would mean neither the client nor the server could be accessed outside of the network nor access any hardware not connected to the internal network.  Please provide a screenshot to explain how your network is currently setup.

Comment: Can you just disconnect your router from the Internet, and isolate your entire network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the IP on Windows 7 from DHCP to a static IP. With a static IP you need to provide the IP, the net mask, the gateway and the DNS servers. If you leave the gateway field blank, then Windows 7 can only reach IP addresses in its own network. If you put the router's IP into the gateway field, then Windows 7 will send all packets for IPs which are not in its own network to your router and the router will do the routing into the internet.

Read your router's manual to check which IP addresses are free to use and which are reserved for the routers DHCP server.

Comment: just keep in mind that is not protecting you if the someone (or some software) at the Windows PC is able to change the gateway (having administrative privileges).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do from the computer. If your router has some sort of parental controls, you may be able to do it there, but not from your computer.